# 3rd page is not click able in pagination

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have used below code for pagination, 2nd page is able to click but next pages are not able to click

```
List<WebElement> pagination = driver.findElements(By.tagName("i"));

List<WebElement> pagination1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cpHFooter_PageUC1_rptrPager_ctl05_lnkNext']/i"));

pagination.size(); 

System.out.println("Total pages :" + pagination.size()); 

if(pagination .size()>0)

{ 

    System.out.println("pagination exists");

    //click on pagination link

    for(int i=0; i<pagination1.size(); i++)

    { 

        pagination1.get(i).click();

        JavascriptExecutor jse1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

        jse1.executeScript("scroll(0, 2000);");

    } 
} 

else 

{ 

    System.out.println("pagination not exists"); 

}
```

Comment: What happens?  What does `not able to click` mean?

Comment: There are 4 pages in pagination, 2nd page button get clicked but next(3rd, 4th) button not click able

Comment: You have to try from page 2

Comment: you're looping though `pagination1` not `pagination`, is that intentional?

Comment: Yeah this is intentional. I am trying to get number of pages in pagination. There are 4 pages but it prints only 2 pages. I tried maximum of codes

Comment: How can you do `if(pagination .size()>0)` and then within the `for()` block do `for(int i=0; i<pagination1.size(); i++)` ? Update the question with your exact _Manual Steps_ and relevant _HTML_ .

Comment: @Debanjan, I don't understand what you saying

Answer (score 0):

You have to start from page 2 and use some wait or `sleep()`

```
List<WebElement> pagination = driver.findElements(By.tagName("i"));

List<WebElement> pagination1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cpHFooter_PageUC1_rptrPager_ctl05_lnkNext']/i"));

pagination.size(); 

System.out.println("Total pages :" + pagination.size()); 

if(pagination .size()>0)

{ 

    System.out.println("pagination exists");

    //click on pagination link

    for(int i=2; i<pagination1.size(); i++)

    { 

        pagination1.get(i).click();

       Thread.sleep(5000); 

        JavascriptExecutor jse1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

        jse1.executeScript("scroll(0, 2000);");


    } 
} 

else 

{ 

    System.out.println("pagination not exists"); 

}
```

Comment: I tried the above code, now not even a single page get clicked

Comment: Pleaese provide UR"L

Comment: arrow URL: .//*[@id='ctl00_cpHFooter_PageUC1_rptrPager_ctl05_lnkNext']/i

Comment: 2nd page url: .//*[@id='ctl00_cpHFooter_PageUC1_rptrPager_ctl02_lnkPage']                                            
                                                                                                                    
 I am using arrow URL